# Why "FALSE" becomes a zero when assigned as part of a vector

Tags: r, vector

Why, in R, is it that:

```r
a <- FALSE
a
#> [1] FALSE
```

But

```r
b <- c(FALSE, 1)
b
#> [1] 0 1
```

Isn't `a`, a vector of length one? Why the behavior differs for a vector of length two?

Is this because all vector elements must be of the same type?

<sup>Created on 2021-03-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you say, a vector has a type, and all elements of the vector are coerced into the most inclusive type that can contain as much of the original information as possible.

```r
typeof(FALSE) # logical
typeof(c(FALSE, 1)) # double, i.e. double-precision numeric
typeof(c(FALSE, 1, 'a')) # character
```

To keep different types, you need a list:

```r
b <- list(FALSE, 1)
```

This works because each entry of a list has its own type.

Why have different types?  A `logical` can be stored using less memory (one bit per entry) than a `double` (64 bits per entry), and can also be processed more quickly in certain situations.

Comment: So a numeric type has more information than a logical type?

Comment: @Emy yes, `logical` class vectors have 3 possible values - `TRUE`, `FALSE`, `NA`. There are more than 3 integers [citation needed], so the `integer` class needs to be able to contain more information, and the double `numeric` class even more than `integer`.